# Accessing Linked list across modules in C#

Tags: c#, pointers

I have previously worked with Linked list in C++ where refering link list in different modules using pointer to acxcess the address of it.

What I use to do is after creating the linked list use to store the address of the Linked list in long format. In another module is same application after type casting the address I am able to reconstruct the linked list.

New if C# world and not able to find a way to implement it. Please help me

Comment: What do you mean different modules? Trying to compare this notion to the C# world

Comment: Is this a desktop application or a web application?

Comment: You don't have to cast it. You can store and pass it as a variable / field / property of LinkedList type. This is the .NET framework class that implements LinkedList: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx

Comment: You should not store address to a long format. The refferency in CLR is not a pointer, it can be remapped to the other adsress in any time (GC process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just hold a reference to your Linked List and use it again whenever you need it?

```
LinkedList mylist = new LinkedList();
```

Now use `mylist` in whatever place you need it, by passing it around, preferrably.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably don't know in C# by default all types except  value types (simple types like int, string etc.) are passed in parameters as a reference to the object.